# Remove certain points from point shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, sorting

I have a point shapefile with 9674 points.  The attribute column has three fields: X, Y and value. Out of these 9674 points, I want to remove 1700 points based on X and Y values (I know the X and Y of these 1700 points) and create a new point shapefile consisting of the remaining 7974 points.

I could easily do Sort Ascending and select the 1700 points but the problem is these 1700 points are scattered across the original shapefile and cannot not be arranged in an order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just select the features you want to keep with a query, save as a new feature class, then flip the selection set,  and save as again?

Comment: do you have a table with the 1700 points you want to remove?

Answer (score 1):

Try to "Select by expression" under Geometry you will find `$x`and `$y` to build the expression you need.

You can then use "Save As" and check only selectet features to save the selection to a new file/shape.

edit: I missed the arcmap label, still this should be possible there too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of the 1700 points to remove, you can [display these points as XY coordinates](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/add-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm). **Select all** of the original shape file points then use [Select by location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) to **remove from the selection** the points that match the 1700.

This selection can then be exported as a new shape file.